# Sendmail configuration

Tags: mail, joomla

I have done the fol­low­ing:

1. Install send­mail and con­fig­ure `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` by adding line:

   DAEMON_OPTIONS(‘Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1′`)dnl
2. Configure joomla mail server set­ting = send­mail
3. php.ini: `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail –i –t`

Mail server only work­ing if I send email from local server, but when am try­ing send email from web­site via Inter­net that not work­ing!

**ANY HELP**

Information:
-i have a public ip and domain name . 
-website and mail server (sendmail) in same server with ubuntu OS

i got the following error : 
`PHPMAILER_EXECUTE/usr/sbin/sendmail`, and i tried configure mail server in joomla to php mail function: `could not instantiate php mail function`

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to edit `/etc/mail/submit.mc` (the local submission half) instead of `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` (the network-listening daemon half). Don't forget to run the "make" command `/etc/mail` after you've made changes.